# Is there a reason not to share hosts for OSDs and Radosgw in a Ceph setup?

Tags: ceph

I am performance testing Ceph.  I have a limited number of VMs to do this with.  I want to have several radosgws, for a round-robin set up.  Will my bechmarks be grossly inaccurate if I use the same hosts for OSDs and radosgw?

Answer (score 0):

Main issue with sharing OSD with any other part of installation, is a thread count. Ceph OSD daemon creates a lot of threads during high load (you want to use Ceph under high load, aren't you?). I can't say how many threads radosgw creates, but it is a well known problem with scenario 'OSDs on compute hosts'. When you have too many threads, OS scheduler starts to mess up with them, threshing CPU cache and significantly drops performance (and raises latencies).

Answer (score 0):

Ceph RGW is light weight process, does not require much CPU and Memory but it does require Network bandwidth. IMO you can collocate RGWs and OSDs provided that you have dedicated Ceph cluster and public networks and RGW should use Ceph public network.

I have done a similar kind of performance benchmarking which includes co-located and dedicated RGWs. I have not found significant performance difference between the two configurations. Co-located RGWs were performing a bit less ( but not substantial difference ).

So if one has to design a low cost object storage solution based on Ceph , then he might want to consider co-locating RGWs on OSDs. You can save some $$

FYI , co-located RGW configuration is not a supported configuration from RedHat point of view. Things are progressing preety fast in that direction.